# how to associate AWS access key ID to (elastic beanstack) eb CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The documentation talks about 2nd step here: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html

but when I try I do not get prompted for keys.  AM I missing something?

```
~/school-site# eb init

Select a default region
1) us-east-1 : US East (N. Virginia)
2) us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
3) us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
4) eu-west-1 : EU (Ireland)
5) eu-central-1 : EU (Frankfurt)
6) ap-south-1 : Asia Pacific (Mumbai)
7) ap-southeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Singapore)
8) ap-southeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Sydney)
9) ap-northeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
10) ap-northeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Seoul)
11) sa-east-1 : South America (Sao Paulo)
12) cn-north-1 : China (Beijing)
13) us-east-2 : US East (Ohio)
14) ca-central-1 : Canada (Central)
15) eu-west-2 : EU (London)
(default is 3): 6

Select an application to use
1) school-site
2) [ Create new Application ]
(default is 1): 1

It appears you are using Python. Is this correct?
(y/n): y

Select a platform version.
1) Python 3.4
2) Python
3) Python 2.7
4) Python 3.4 (Preconfigured - Docker)
(default is 1): 3
Do you want to set up SSH for your instances?
(y/n): n

# eb --version
EB CLI 3.9.1 (Python 2.7.6)
```

Comment: I would assume that the cli found credentials so it did not prompt for them, per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-credentials.

Comment: I removed .elasticbeanstack folder from my working directory and removed ~/.ssh/ as well so it has no way to look for credentials.

Comment: AWS credentials would not be in ~/.ssh/. They'd be in one of the places listed in the link I shared (environment variables, ~/.aws/credentials, ~/.aws/config or in your instace profile if running on EC2).